# Current User in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, timezone

I have a question I am really new in Rails and I'm not sure what is correct.

```
  def current_user
   return unless params[:user_id]
   @current_user ||= User.find(params[:user_id])
 end
```

So like this I get the current user. Rails check the params for user_id.

But what if I something like that the route `/users/:id`
Then the params is id and not user_id this is why it fails sometimes with to set the time zone correctly. 
How to handle something like this ?

```
 def set_time_zone(&block)
    if params[:user]
      Time.use_zone(params[:user][:time_zone], &block)
    else
      time_zone = current_user.try(:time_zone) || 'UTC'
      Time.use_zone(time_zone, &block)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could override the `current_user` inside the `UsersController` so that it looks at the `id` param instead of `user_id`. or you can use the existing method with a fallback like so:

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) || User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

i'd caution you though not to take that `params[:id]` for granted. if my user id is 5 there's nothing to stop me from visiting `/users/6`!

Comment: could try `find_by(:id, params[:user_id])` instead but not sure why this is undefined - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders

Comment: `User.find` will throw an exception if it's not found whereas `find_by`/`find_by_id` will not

Comment: Thank you @Substantial you mad it :D

Answer (score 1):

In all the rails apps i've seen so far `current_user` represents the currently logged in user.
The id of the currently logged in user MUST NEVER be sent via `params` but via `session` (because params can be manipulated by everybody).

1. User submits username/password via form
2. controller verifies username/password matches and if correct
3. sets id of user to session

Then you can have

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= begin
    User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

in your application controller.